# What is a suitable age for Good Teak tree?

Tags: trees

I was just thinking of growing 4-5 teak trees in my backyard garden as an investment. Does any one know whats a good age for a teak tree to be cut down to be sold ?

I just figured since we have a big land and good soil, so why not try out a teak tree, rather than any other tree. 
My ultimate goal for this would be selling them much later when I get old and use it as a retirement investment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure as I am from another corner of the world, but a quick (non-conclusive) websearch, for example [here](http://www.istf-bethesda.org/specialreports/teca_teak/teak.pdf) and [here](https://www.panamateakforestry.com/english/company_profile/teak-plantation-management.php), suggests something between 25 and 60 years. Assuming that you want thick trees (= significantly more value), I'd aim for the upper end of this range. Besides, teak is supposed to grow slowly for best quality.

Remember that the currently *oh so modern* term "sustainability" was coined 300 years ago by [Hans Carl v. Carlowitz](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Carl_von_Carlowitz) in Germany with regards to forestry. I'm from the Black Forest myself, where [wood](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Forest%23Forestry) was (and to some degree still is) a significant source of income for centuries. If you intend to plant trees for your own retirement, I hope that you are a) quite young and b) have a "Plan B". Here in the Black Forest one sells trees that were planted by the grandfather or father and plants trees for the benefit of children and grandchildren.

If you simply happen to own a piece of land and have no better use for it, go for it and plant a few trees, but do it for fun, not for economic reasons. If you can sell a bit of timber in a few decades, it will be a neat little windfall, but don't count on it, there simply are too many things that may go wrong.

Comment: Thanks, actually I did do a lot of research before posting the question. I found that there were lots of mixed answers to the question on different sites. Some said 9 years was enough , and some plantations said they grow for 10 years and then sell it. Some even had 5(which was probably wrong) . And Some said over 20 . But those papers were definitely good .